# Arduino pin always high and other blink at same time

Tags: arduino

I need a pin always high without delay 
and in same time one pin blink

Can someone help?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I try this code, but the bluetooth light isn't always linked


int led = 13;
int bluetooth = 11;
int lamp = 12;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lamp, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluetooth, OUTPUT);
  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(bluetooth, HIGH);
  
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(lamp, HIGH);
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(lamp, LOW);
  delay(5000);
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```cpp
byte highPin = 12;
byte blinkPin = 11;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(highPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(blinkPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(highPin, HIGH);
}
    
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(blinkPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000); //Delay for 1 second      
  digitalWrite(blinkPin, LOW);
  delay(1000); //Change this also
}
```

Since the setup function runs only once, the highPin (12) will be set high, once. The blinkPin has its state changed in the loop. We turn it on for one second, turn it off for one second, and repeat.

Hook led one to pin 11 and led 2 to pin 12. Let me know if you need anything else!